# Self-Referential Structures

Tags: c, pointers, struct

The self-referential structure is defined the following way:

```
struct node{
    int data1;
    int data2;
    struct node *ptr;
}obj,*temp;

int main()
{
     printf("\n Address of variable data1 in struct is %p",&obj.data1);
     printf("\n Address of variable data2 in struct is %p",&obj.data2);
}
```

The o/p is

> Address of variable data1 in struct is 0xd0c7010
>   Address of variable data2 in struct is 0xd0c7018

which means that `data1` is occupying 8 bytes of memory, right?

But if I have the following structure definition

```
struct node{
    int data1;
    int data2;
}obj,*temp;

int main()
{
     printf("\n Address of variable data1 in struct is %p",&obj.data1);
     printf("\n Address of variable data2 in struct is %p",&obj.data2);
}
```

The o/p is

> Address of variable data1 in struct is 0xd0c6010
>   Address of variable data2 in struct is 0xd0c6014

So `data1` is occupying 4 bytes of memory which an integer variable do, right?

But why in the first case is the memory space occupied by `data1` increased?

EDIT:
 For the first case o/p is

```
Address of variable data1 in struct is 0x600940
Address of variable data2 in struct is 0x600944
The address of ptr is 0x600948
The size of struct is 16
```

For the second case

```
 Address of variable data1 in struct is 0x600910
 Address of variable data2 in struct is 0x600914
 The size of struct is 8
```

I am running this code on Linux using 
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2

The above code works fine but what about this below one

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

// This function prints contents of linked list starting from the given node
void printList(struct node *n)
{
  printf("\n The memory location of n is %p ",n);
  while (n != NULL)
  {
     printf(" %d ", n->data);
     n = n->next;
     printf("\n The memory location of n in while loop is %p ",n);
  }
}

int main()
{
  struct node* head = NULL;
  struct node* second = NULL;
  struct node* third = NULL;

  // allocate 3 nodes in the heap
  head  = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  second = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  third  = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  head->data = 1; //assign data in first node
  head->next = second; // Link first node with the second node
  printf("\n The memory address of head->data is %p ",&head->data);
  printf("\n The memory address of head->next is %p ",&head->next);

  second->data = 2; //assign data to second node
  second->next = third;
  printf("\n The memory address of second->data is %p ",&second->data);
  printf("\n The memory address of second->next is %p ",&second->next);

  third->data = 3; //assign data to third node
  third->next = NULL;

  printf("\n The memory address of third->data is %p ",&third->data);
  printf("\n The memory address of third->next is %p ",&third->next);

  printList(head);

  getchar();
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

O/P is

```
 The memory address of head->data is 0x215c010
 The memory address of head->next is 0x215c018
 The memory address of second->data is 0x215c030
 The memory address of second->next is 0x215c038
 The memory address of third->data is 0x215c050
 The memory address of third->next is 0x215c058
 The memory location of n is 0x215c010  1
 The memory location of n in while loop is 0x215c030  2
 The memory location of n in while loop is 0x215c050  3
 The memory location of n in while loop is (nil)
```

Why now there is still a difference of 8 bytes?
I am running this code under the same environment as the other two.

Comment: Can you say what system and compiler version you are using?

Comment: @Charles I am using gcc compiler and version gcc (GCC) 4.1.2

Comment: Regarding your edit, everything looks fine for me. Always a padding of 4 Bytes.

Comment: Well i am also wondering the same now but earlier There were 8 bytes difference I am checking it again

Comment: Well take a look for my last comment on the first answer. Maybe the compiler did some weird stuff and moved the pointer to the struct between data1 and data2?

Comment: HAHAHA That's exactly i thiought. I ve compiled the code 3-4 times and getting the 4 bytes padding everytime weirdo compiler

Comment: Beginner programmers often do not control well what is in their sources, and "weirdo compiler" means actual compiler misbehavior in less than or equal to 0% cases. In your first case, the source was not exactly what you presented here, and in last chunk, both members are 8-byte pointers, not ints, thus 8-byte difference.

Comment: You have contradictory claims for the output from the first example.  Frankly, the second output, showing a difference of 4 bytes in the addresses of `data1` and `data2` is more plausible than the first output, showing a difference of 8 bytes; I don't believe the first output is accurate.  That said, the compiler is entitled to add padding to a structure if it wishes to do so.

Comment: **both members are 8-byte pointers, not ints** well data is declared as an int while next is a struct pointer

Comment: Missed that int, apologies. It is second ptr that aligned to 8-byte boundary due to 8-byte size. It is all well after EDIT point.

Comment: Okay agreed that the second pointer is aligned at an 8 byte boundries but data is int is at the location **the memory address of second->data is 0x215c030**  so data occupies 4 bytes rt so shuouldn't then **the memory address of third->next is 0x215c058** be **0x215c054** as data would use ony 4 bytes

Comment: No, because 8-byte pointers are aligned on 8-byte boundary. 4-byte int, 4-byte unused, 8-byte ptr, total size 16. If you swap the two, then total size would be 12. Unaligned load/stores may be inefficient or faulty on various platforms, thus alignment exists.

Comment: @user3125367: you're right about the 4 int, 4 unused, 8 pointer; but reversing the order of the data and the pointer simply moves the padding to the end of the structure instead of in the middle; it will still be 16 bytes long because the size has to be big enough to ensure that an array of the type with the zeroth element of the array properly aligned will also preserve proper alignment for every subsequent element of the array.  If the size was 12 bytes, then `array[1].ptr` would be aligned on a 4-byte boundary instead of an 8-byte boundary, which is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Struct padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) is the reason for the difference you observe.

I think you are on a 64 bit systems where pointer size is 8 bytes (in the struct with a pointer). So the compiler aligns all the three members to 8 byte alignment. But in the later case, it's only two `int`'s, so it's aligned to 4 bytes.

Comment: If the compiler can align `int` to 4 byte boundaries on this system it would still make sense to put the two `int` into one 8-byte block and the pointer in the adjacent 8-byte block, though?

Comment: @CharlesBailey What you say also makes sense. But I am not sure why. Perhaps, OP can update with the address of the pointer member  in the struct,  `sizeof` both structs and the platform details which would explain exactly what happens.

Comment: OP's result doesn't match mine with gcc 4.9.2 on x86_64.

Comment: Well i tested the code on a archlinux 64bit and the result for the first try was a 4byte-difference. So maybe, MAYBE, the compiler the OP is using did put the pointer to the struct between data1 and data2. So maybe he outputs the adress of the structpointer as well so that we/he can see.

Comment: It would be a very unusual compiler that introduced padding between the two 4-byte `int` values.  Totally unorthodox.  Not technically wrong, but I've never seen a compiler blunder like that.  Structure padding might be the cause, but if so, it means that the compiler is long overdue for upgrading.  And frankly, I don't think there was a bug that big in GCC 4.1.2.

Comment: I think this hypothesis is just wrong, mostly because there is no matter which fields follow after two ints. It may also break ABI even inside the same translation unit (we usually expect that common-header structs are compatible). OP just messed with srcs or compilation phase and presented unrelated output.

Comment: @user3125367 What Charles Bailey commented is the more plausible explanation but how else OP saw those addresses? And OP updated the post with the info, I asked for. From that it's clear that for both cases, it's only a 4 byte alignment.

Comment: @BlueMoon Edit, save, (forget to build), run, wonder. Edit, (forget to save), build, run, wonder. Copy common header for debug purposes, work on copy, include original somewhere (header guards haha). Lots of methods out there. OPs often present their X –> Y version, not mentioning nor controlling the details of "–>".